# How to deal with a question whose title doesn't match?

Tags: discussion, questions, title, answer-quality

I just read this question:

[Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)

Where the question title and body are completely different questions (for reference, the body is asking how to determine whether branch A has been merged into branch B). My first thought on seeing it, was to edit the title to make it clear what the OP is actually asking.

However, I see that the question an answer to both the question in the title, and another answer to the question in the body text. Is there anything I can do about this? Or should do?

The OP is asking two distinct questions, which should really be separate posts. I don't want to edit the title, because then people searching for it won't find the post. On the other hand, people who have the same question as the OP will currently have trouble finding the post, because the title doesn't appear relevant. The fact that the answer to the question title has 30+ more upvotes than the answer to the question body I think shows that this is a real problem. Is there maybe some kind of split question function?

**tl;dr:** How should we handle cases where someone has posted two unrelated questions as a single post, and they both have good answers with many upvotes?

Edit:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710951/494643), with 96 upvotes and accepted, answers the question in the body text.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207176/494643), with 132 upvotes, answers the question in the title.

Comment: The question title does make it sounds like it's asking for something along the lines of `git log <branchA>..<branchB>`, but I haven't taken a close look at the question body yet. However, for what it's worth, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4061481/456814) also had a title that didn't describe the actual question well, until I edited it.

Comment: @Cupcake Slightly different though, that question just had a poorly worded title, rather than a title that appears to belong to an entirely different question.

Comment: I disagree the title "doesn't match" the body. The title describes how the user thought they could solve the problem; the objective is described in the question, followed by the same question as the title again. The accepted answer addresses the objective,  discarding (rightly IMO) the x/y proposed solution in the question. The meta-answer is always the same: edit the question to make it clearer _if you can_, in this case though there are numerous answers addressing the title question - so IMO it should stay as it is (users asking the same question can see answers and a better way® too).

Comment: Since the community is split and the Stack Overflow folks have not answered, is it safe to assume the actions should be Close with "Unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: I have found another question with the same problem [implode array keys only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614397/implode-array-keys-only). The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11477613/491245) with more votes,146, answer the title and the [accepted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8614435/491245) (with 2) answer the body. What to do?

Comment: This Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966977/get-only-the-drive-letter-from-a-path-in-powershell has a similar problem, the title and answers match, but the body of the Q does not match either the title or the answers. The title to match the body would be closer to `How to find the share path from a network drive letter?`

Comment: Particularly egregious example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/
Title asks if duplicate HTMLIDs can happen, but the body asks if it's valid. Both are yes or no questions, but first answer is yes and the second answer is no. Some contention in the answers and comments is reflective of this.